# How to include section numbers in InDesign Table of Contents

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

I am trying to create a Table of Contents for a book in InDesign. Each page of the book has a section marker and page number (e.g. 1-3). I set it up that way so that the section marker and page number would appear in the TOC, based on what I read on Adobe InDesign Help:

> If you want number prefixes (such as 1-1, 1-3, and so on) to appear in your table of contents, use section numbering rather than chapter numbering. Section number prefixes can be included in a table of contents.

However, the section markers are not appearing in the Table of Contents. There doesn't seem to be any way to indicate that they are supposed to be shown, and I can't find any more documentation about how to include them. Can anyone help?

Comment: I have done a little more Googling. Some people say that section markers don't appear in the TOC if they are on master pages, so the only way to make them appear is to override the master header on every single page. Is this true? It seems very counterintuitive since I can't imagine when someone would use a section marker *except* on a master page!

Comment: Did you try making a new master for each section?

Comment: @LaurenIpsum Each section is a separate document. I used "Load Master Pages" to start off creating each doc's master pages, and then modified them so each section/doc would have a unique master header. I don't know if that counts as "new" though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question because I have finally (finally!!!) figured it out. You are supposed to use **section prefixes**, not section markers. To mark page 2-1, for instance, put 2- in the prefix box and make sure "Include Prefix When Numbering Pages" is checked.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this! It's not a very intuitive process when following others' explanations. This is perfect!